# How to use a PDF as backgound in more than one page per chapter?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, backgrounds

I want to insert a pdf as background in my book but not all pages

```
\chapter{Creativity}
\label{chap:Creativity}

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
    \put(0,0){
    \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
    \vfill
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{2_orange_bars.pdf}
    \vfill
    }}}
    
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
\maketitle
```

I used  this code in latex, but the problem when I want to use it again in the same chapter I got an error message that it's already used and the generated book have only 1 page with that design.

PS: I don't like a background to all pages, but few ones for example from page 2--> page 16

Comment: Use only the `\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}` on the second page?

Comment: Yes It works thank you so much ! But I'm obliged to put it every time below the section, is there an option to add a loop ?

Comment: sure, lots of things are possible. But your question doesn't give any details what you actually want and where the picture should appear and where not; also your code is not compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work on selected pages.  In this case pages 2-3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikz}% not really needed, but easier than \rlap{\hspace{-1in}\raisebox{1in}[0pt][0pt]{...}}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\AddEverypageHook{% do pages 2-3
\ifnum\value{page} > 1
  \ifnum\value{page} < 4
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \fi
\fi}
  
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

---

This version uses the new \AddToHook comand.  No packages needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{% do pages 2-3
\ifnum\value{page} > 1
  \ifnum\value{page} < 4
    \put(0pt,-\paperheight) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}%
  \fi
\fi}
  
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: IT works well, but I got a weird problem, before the book cover I got 3 pages with a text in a weird language added 
Could you suggest what is the reason from this code ?

Comment: no it still there at the beginning of the PDF. I'm using overleaf online version

Comment: Ops :( Is there another way to add background PDF in all pages except index / coverbook ?

Comment: Does removing the AddEverypageHook fix the problem?  Try reordeing the preamble.

Comment: well I removed this package %\usepackage{lipsum}
and the call for it! It works well much better, the only problem when I want it to start from page 1 the cover book disappear, when I want it to start from page 2 the cover is back but table of content didn't contain the background on its first page.

Comment: See also \AtShipout,

Comment: I just removed this one before table of content \frontmatter, it works perfectly! :)